# INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE in Windows when booting from USB

Tags: windows, usb, bsod, windows-to-go

I have installed Windows on a removable USB drive, but whenever I try to boot from it, it bluescreens with an error code of `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`. Why does this happen, and how can I make it boot again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/16148-can-i-boot-windows-hdd-via-usb-inaccessible_boot_device.html) thread, the USB 3.0 drivers aren't loaded at the stage of the boot process where Windows tries to access the boot partition.

To make Windows load the USB drivers sooner:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Enter `HKLM\SYSTEM\HardwareConfig\` in the address bar at the top
3. On the left, choose the entry with the UUID of the boot partition
4. Change `BootDriverFlags`'s value to `14` (hexadecimal)

Answer (score 0):

USBPcap can cause this on Windows To Go as well: https://github.com/desowin/usbpcap/issues/61

(Note that removing usbpcap from UpperFilters actually disables usbpcap)