# Windows to go INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE USB

Tags: usb, ssd, windows-11, bsod, windows-to-go

Laptop : Lenovo P14s Gen2 Intel version

Windows 11 Pro Go to installed on Cruicial SSD using rufus v4

Laptop belongs to my company, I just finished my grad with my 7yrs old laptop. Wanted to play games but can't afford to buy new laptop. I had Segate External hhd which as a usb 2.0 detachable SATA connector by using that I connected by SSD to laptop all working from last 1 month. Finally achieved to play GTAV (go 2023).

I don't know what happened from last 2 days, I'm getting Inaccessible boot device, but it's working in friend pc. points to note
1.Company disk bitlocker protected & offline in Windows go to boot
2.windows update disabled
3. Local account

**What I tried and results**

automatic repair never worked, went to boot cmd-> checked bcdedit,diskpart

bcdedit bootmgr volume pointing out to volume1 and osdevice & device partition to C: but my win goto drive letter d: & volume 4

wanted to change the above c: to d: but it saying unable to access. at this point I got confused which os bcdedit i was looking.

Some files missing I thought , so re installed win 11 22h2 pro go to again on ssd but same issue . I don't know what to do kindly help. my games are waiting for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INACCESSIBLE\_BOOT\_DEVICE in Windows when booting from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/1718225/inaccessible-boot-device-in-windows-when-booting-from-usb)

Comment: got it let try and update

Comment: Also, can you please edit your question with more info about what happens when you try to boot.  For example what steps are completed, where does it fail, what if any additional messages do you see before or after the error on the screen, does it go into a boot loop, does it freeze etc.

Comment: If you do any more testing editing your answer to include screenshots may be helpful as well as a link to the instructions you are using to install e.g. [How to create a Windows to Go version of Windows 11](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-a-windows-to-go-version-of-windows-11)

Comment: This laptop belongs to your company. Have you spoken with your company IT about using their laptop in this way?